# TLS version support for BizTalk 2016

Tags: biztalk, tls1.2, biztalk-2016

How can I check on which TLS version our BizTalk 2016 server is running

I want to know if TLS1.2 is not enabled how can I enable the same on BizTalk 2016 server.

Answer (score 0):

As BizTalk 2016 is on .Net 4.6 this tries to use TLS 1.2 first but falls back to TLS 1.1 & TLS 1.0 unless they are disabled.

[MS16-065: Description of the TLS/SSL protocol information disclosure vulnerability (CVE-2016-0149): May 10, 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3155464/ms16-065-description-of-the-tls-ssl-protocol-information-disclosure-vu)

> Note The .NET Framework 4.6 and later versions use TLS 1.2, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.0 as the protocol defaults. This is discussed in the Microsoft Security Advisory 2960358 topic on the Microsoft TechNet website.

If you want to make BizTalk use TLS 1.2 exclusively you need to make sure you have either [Feature Pack 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/biztalk/core/configure-the-feature-pack#feature-pack-2-updates) or Feature Pack 3 (I would recommend the latest always), or if not installing feature packs, install [CU 5 for BizTalk 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/4132957/cumulative-update-5-for-microsoft-biztalk-server-2016).   You also need to ensure that any system BizTalk connects to, including the BizTalk database server support TLS 1.2

**Note** there is a prerequisite:

SQL Server 2012 Native Client version 11 should be installed on all BizTalk Server systems before you apply this update. If the SQL Native Client is not installed before you apply cumulative update, the installation may not complete.

Both of those articles then link you to [Support for TLS 1.2 protocol in BizTalk Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/4091110/support-for-tls-1-2-protocol-in-biztalk-server) and also links leading to [MS16-065: Description of the TLS/SSL protocol information disclosure vulnerability (CVE-2016-0149): May 10, 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3155464/ms16-065-description-of-the-tls-ssl-protocol-information-disclosure-vu)

Comment: Thanks for the above. @dijkgraaf
I am calling a third party web service which only allows request with TLS1.2 how can i make sure that all the request from our BizTalk2016 server is made with TLS1.2.
We have feature pack 3 installed to our servers

Comment: @ParthAjmani  BizTalk 2016 on .Net 4.6+ should try with TLS1.2 initially, have you tried connecting and are having issues?

Comment: Hi, We have successfully upgraded to FP 3, but still get an error while calling an API end point from BizTalk. Do we need to add the below line of code anywhere in BizTalk to use TLS 1.2
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;